# rust, WebAssembly, and passing arguments for increased total memory

Tags: rust, asm.js, webassembly

I have a rust project I am compiling to webasm per http://asquera.de/blog/2017-04-10/the-path-to-rust-on-the-web/

Project compiles. When I run it in Chrome Canary, it runs out of memory and gives me a very helpful error message:

```
abort("Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with  -s 
TOTAL_MEMORY=X  with X higher than the current value 16777216, (2) compile 
with  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1  which allows increasing the size at runtime, 
...
```

Problem is, its not clear how to pass those flags to rustc / the build tool chain.

Neither  setting EMMAKEN_CFLAGS or  the following work:

```
cargo  rustc -v --target=wasm32-unknown-emscripten --release -- -Clink-args="-s TOTAL_MEMORY=33554432"
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://gregkatz.github.io/2017-05-20-rust-emscripten.html) blog post offers a solution that I think can be applied in your case too:

> As best as I can tell there is no way to pass most linker arguments through cargo. Instead, hack around the limitation by specifying a custom linker that is actually a shell script wrapping the real linker.

Create a shell script like `emcc_link` that calls emscripten with the appropriate options:

```
emcc "-s" "TOTAL_MEMORY=33554432" $@
```

(You may need other options to make it work. Check the [blog post](https://gregkatz.github.io/2017-05-20-rust-emscripten.html) for details.)

And specify to use it for your project by editing/creating [`.cargo/config`](http://doc.crates.io/config.html):

```
[target.wasm32-unknown-emscripten]
linker = "/your/project/dir/emcc_sdl"

[target.asmjs-unknown-emscripten]
linker = "/your/project/dir/emcc_sdl"
```

I ruthlessly assumed the build environment is Linux or the like. On Windows the shell script should probably be a batch script and I'm not sure if there are any differences in `.cargo/config`.

Disclaimer: I have not tried any of this.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. But need to do some digging to be sure. In particular, it appears that the special linker is never invoked with a .cargo/config in the project directory

Comment: This is hard to debug.. cargo does not complain about invalid settings in the config file as long it's valid Toml. What happens if you pass the linker directly to rustc with `-C linker=`?